# Text alignment to left changes while changing starting text letter

Tags: html, css

Here i have a text "Wake", when i change "Wake" to "Make", it took extra space from left like half a pixel extra margin from left.

I have changed @font-face from woff to otf with css properties

```
font-kerning: normal;
```

and

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-feature-settings: "kern";
font-kerning: normal;
```

but none worked for me !!!

Browser : 
Chrome: 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
FireFox: 53.0.2 (64-bit)

[image: correct image]
[image: incorrect image alignment]

Comment: Did you replace it with an "M" or a "W"? Also, it might be irrelevant, but why are you changing it in the first place?

Comment: Thats just an example , given text dynamic it could be any thing "M" , "Y", "W" etc

Comment: Maybe your font has used not full glyph space for letter and it shows gap then?

Comment: make sure you are using a monospace font, all characters will occupy the same width.

Comment: It works fine with all other letters but its behave weird with "M" !!!

Comment: Please make a fiddle

Comment: @Justinas : Why only with "M" ?

Comment: The M just has more space to the left of it than the A. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vuy8n5w6/). I don't see how this is a problem. Edit: the same is true for other letters with vertical left stems, such as the B,D, E, F, H and K. Not only the M!

Comment: By the way, font-kerning works only with the space in between letters, not with the position of the first letter. If you take a word such as **WAKE** and you play with the font-kerning, the first letter won't change position, only the A and the rest does.

Comment: @Lister , i didnt knw that , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you are not using a monospaced font, that means the large of some letters are bigger than others, normally M is the most bigger on this type of fonts and that causes your text to move.

I doubt there is a pure CSS solution for this, at least that looks good because most of the letters will have a different proportion so you need to calculate the width and resize them looking on the letters you have.

Found a possible JS solution: [Force Non-Monospace Font into Fixed Width Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149330/force-non-monospace-font-into-fixed-width-using-css)

Information to underestand your problem:

[From Wikipedia Monospaced font source:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

> A **monospaced font**, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or
>   non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each
>   occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with
>   variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different
>   widths. For example, the two high-use letters "I" and "E" do not need
>   the same footprint. Both letters differ in center-to-next-letter edge
>   (and center-to-center) spacing distance needs (margins) in variable
>   width fonts. The variable that changes is offset from what would
>   otherwise be monospaced centering. In a modern proportional font,
>   every dimension can be scaled and changed, but such sizing
>   mathematically must still maintain monospacing or variable spacing.

**Examples:**

No monospaced font:

```css
div {
  font-size: 142px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>AAA</div>
<div>MMM</div>
```

Monospaced font:

```css
div {
  font-size: 142px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>AAA</div>
<div>MMM</div>
```

Comment: The OP means the A is in a different starting position than the M, not that they are of different widths. See also my [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vuy8n5w6/).

Comment: @MrLister Now change to a mono font and see: www.jsfiddle.net/vuy8n5w6/1 , they start from the same position because they have the same proportions :P

Comment: Not on my machine, because I don't have a font called 'Mono'.

Comment: @MrLister I tried with another one now `Courier New` there: http://jsfiddle.net/vuy8n5w6/3/ but you can have a look about default Monospace Fonts there: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: @Troyar Thanks for the help , but if i change font to mono, it completely changes font look and feel, which is undesirable. i read in few blogs that we can use font-kerning: normal; but that not working for me !

Comment: @mayank I doubt there's a pure CSS solution for this, maybe there is one JS but believe me it will take time if there is a lot of text, it worths to change to a monospaced font. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149330/force-non-monospace-font-into-fixed-width-using-css

Comment: @MrLister I added some examples on the answer, hope now you can see the problem :)

Comment: @troyer do u think font-kerning: normal; could help here?

Comment: @mayank I don't think it will solve anything because every time the letters have a different proportion, imagine you fix it for M now, but on the future is not an M, is a E, then you need to fix it again.

Answer (score 0):

While not best practice, sometimes just adding a span around a specific letter and then adjusting that span via a class helps solve small rendering issues like this.

For example:

```
<span class="move">M</span>ake
```

and then in the css:

```
.move {
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Then what happens when is not a `M` and it's an `A` ?

Comment: Then you do another span with a different class name.

Comment: Seems very usefull to add 26 classes (one for each letter in the alphabet) extra just for moving 1 px/2 px of margin.