# prevent dynamic text from moving layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, momentjs

I work on a [pet project](https://doomsday.vercel.app/). As you can see by looking at the countdown, text moves a bit when numbers change due to the difference in symbol width. I want numbers to be fixed in place so they won't move anything.

At first I tried making font nums in the font monospaced, it worked but still if the font is to change then it will break.

Then I tried wrapping numbers in a span with fixed width but the catch is the website is adaptive and changes on viewport size so on smallers screens the font becomes smaller and fixed-size span doesn't work.

How can I dynamically calculate font width and add some extra space to the wrapping span to keep the numbers in place? Or maybe there are other approaches to handle this?

Comment: _"but the catch is the website is adaptive and changes on viewport size so on smallers screens the font becomes smaller and fixed-size span doesn't work."_ -  font-size relative length units exist. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_font

Comment: Does this answer your question [Force Non-Monospace Font into Fixed Width Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149330/force-non-monospace-font-into-fixed-width-using-css]=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `width` of an element relative to the *font-size* of the *root* element using the `rem` unit.

Just make sure to also define the *font-size* of the *innerText* in relative size so it does not break based on changes to the root *font-size*.

**My recommendation:**
When I look at your site, I rather recommend to wrap the individual clock elements of 
`X hours : Y minutes : Z seconds`
in 3 individual elements with fixed relative width and `display: inline-block;` so the *value-unit* pairs are not separated and stay together on one line when the line breaks for different viewport sizes.

See this post for more info: [Prevent line-break of span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300760/prevent-line-break-of-span-element)

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to break it in multiple `<p>` tags and give the tag a fixed width

```
<div class="clock-container">
<p class="time">26 years, 7 months, 7 days </p><p class="time" 
style="display: inline-block;width: 978px;"> 13 hours : 28 minutes : 06</p>
<p class="time" style="display: inline-block;">seconds</p>
</div>
```

you can break it further for the minutes and hours.

so to leave the dynamic clock in one `<p>` tag example:

`<span class="time" style="display: inline-block;width: 76px;">66</span>`